# Typescript class method return type based on parameter

Tags: typescript, class, dynamic, interface, return-type

I am trying to create a class with a method whose return type will depend on the `boolean` value of a **flag-parameter**

I have managed to do this successfully when

- using a plain function expression that implements an interface,
- or in a class when declaring the method overloads directly in the class body

However, **I am not able to do this when I am trying to use an interface that is implemented by the class**.

I would like to do this using interface implementation for a class method to achieve the dynamic return type.

Thanks!

Here is the example code which is also available in the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ZAAKIaBiyxTmhmo3zolmZWzxZNJJVXck9MzZvXE5JRZkZLFZdndctcgU8sadfly44K4WijjixYNqUy7ltoUXS1EG47SWgdUgY3wIHKnX4IgIWPxyzOAB0yZHhsgT05AEINRVZ8qAEwLpcrhhrzclg0xXdQVlZQ8gKFPACS8B0SDpkHwSAvE6BDer67yfEIJAUNQwaguCkIgJBIgwU00j4Oe3I5ii3hphimbFvSuakumtYFARRIpqRvQZlWORUUW9xvtOYFXue0ASMwRDVIQWCofwGHkaW9H4C2xwjE2tiiccJxDiKKzdr2ewHIm0ntsOKq9hOjE2s8MBYABQHoGyPyRtGHyurYRCLlilDevw7o0vOGwMEQUJIdBYiSGhADMKmEqo6haFZXiclYlEuG4gWeFgaKQIEz6MoWAhylhiV1nhtE1pyk4RixcYML57GcdxsC8V5-C+ZhJaUZyUmKOJfIqYOZwdvJOCbGOtxKYcDaCi16kHJ1dzjtpTEzpAc5ML5bSLsu+XeTeW75g+TwAOoAEoAPIAHIAOJ5spuSdt2r7jZNAAsF5zfGC0bua96PpAG07ftxE1sd7WLK+75QHAbq-vpgGIMB5l4OUDnwvO7qerATCmiZYFlHl8aXVVwQBR4wUGElYW5hFThRVjOF+HFlZsmWZEpdVua1U1jaNQO8qyR9HWKdKymM31irEUNWlTmdyoAKxXVet23vS24rVAz17QdNBHW1mynZqJ5MAAbCL82LXeuFS09W2y29Ctip9+5AA)

```js
// it works with interface for plain function
interface common {
  <T extends boolean>(flag: T): T extends true ? string : boolean ;
  (flag: boolean): string | boolean;
}
const method: common = (flag: boolean) => {
  if (flag) {
    return 'truhty';
  } else {
    return false ;
  }
}

// it works with plain method overload

function test(flag: true): string
function test(flag: false): boolean
function test(flag: boolean): string | boolean {
  if (flag) {
    return 'truthy'
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

const x = test(true);
const y = test(false);

// This works with direct class method overload

class Exp {
  test(flag: true): string
  test(flag: false): boolean
  test(flag: boolean): string | boolean {
    if (flag) {
      return 'truthy'
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

const val = new Exp().test(false); // boolean!
const val2 = new Exp().test(true); // string!


// It does not work in class with interface overload
interface common2 {
  test(flag: true): string
  test(flag: false): boolean
  test(flag: boolean): string | boolean
}

class Exp2 implements common2 {
  test(flag: boolean) {
    if (flag) {
      return 'truthy'
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

// it is not working in class with generic conditional type

interface common3 {
  test<T extends boolean>(flag: T): T extends true ? string: boolean
  test(flag: boolean): string | boolean
}

class Exp3 implements common3 {
  test(flag: boolean) {
    if (flag) {
      return 'truthy';
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}


const val3 = new Exp3().test(false); // WRONG false | 'truthy'!
const val4 = new Exp3().test(true); // WRONG false | 'truthy'!


// it does not work with conditional directly in class
class Exp4 {
  test<T extends boolean>(flag: T): T extends true ? string : boolean
  test(flag: boolean) {
    if (flag) {
      return 'truthy';
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

const val5 = new Exp3().test(false); // WRONG false | 'truthy'!
const val6 = new Exp3().test(true); // WRONG false | 'truthy'!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer I was looking for on how to use conditional typing on a class method with an interface.

It seems that you can use the interface with its conditional generic, **without** creating all the possible overloads, as long as you **<s>type</s> cast the returned values from the implementation**.

So according to my original post, this would be:

```js
type ResType<T extends boolean> = T extends true ? string : boolean;

interface common3 {
  test<T extends boolean>(flag: T): ResType<T>
}

class Exp3 implements common3 {
  test<T extends boolean>(flag: T): ResType<T> {
    if (flag) {
      return 'truthy' as ResType<T>;
    } else {
      return false as ResType<T>;
    }
  }
}


const val3 = new Exp3().test(false); // boolean
const val4 = new Exp3().test(true); //  string
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOAVcEA8ioQB7AgOwBN4oAjAezIBsIBDPAPigF4oNtdDjgAnAV2gD8UeDwCWeAOZQAXKQrU6AbgCwAKDXjc3AGY0AxtD1kAtsbJ4AzFADeaqFFwj0mHPiJyqtBgAptlGhKyiACUsnBIKOj0agC+amp6-vDEAKJYYFaixmDUxvjAxEam5la2qvaOwM7sbsTknnT0vv6BrKGwCMiQUTZ29lCi2lDNAcG95f323BDAvNx4UADkPLzAABYgi1A0xOFdaIj0KhP2MZiU8NBlk1Mzcwu6F9A7HRHdh8eTcRPf3-GqRjwIigADcaJQrCw8BAAO5QNIZbzBAB0lV84MuwUUUAA9DiPAo8AlzMCwZQACzMKDQuEIixI1EIYDeFYQLG4-HCMSSIA)

Comment: I think you used the wrong playground link there. :-) But note that that's not *typing* the returns, it's using *type assertions* on them. Just typing them would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w66krw) and would still result in an error. Type assertions are sometimes a necessary evil, but they bypass type checking (to a greater or lesser extent). In general, it's best to avoid them.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the link! I fixed it! You are right, I wrote **typing** while it actually is **casting-assertion**!
The funny thing is that, even in the actual [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#conditional-type-constraints) with the conditionally typed `createLabel` function, if you see the referenced playground _(in the **try** button)_ and replace the `throw unimplemented` with the actual implementation, it produces the same error I had! hahaha [TSPlay link](https://tsplay.dev/w8Jy0m)

Comment: Nearly writing the same question, SO redirected me here only to see that I already came up with the answer --- except I am not satisfied because of the two type casts `as ResType<T>`. :-/ I wonder if there is a way to formulate this without the casts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you get a choice but to repeat the overload in the class (as you did with `Exp`) when implementing the interface; here's a modified `Exp2` that both implements the interface and lists the overloads:

```typescript
class Exp2 implements common2 {
  test(flag: true): string;
  test(flag: false): boolean;
  test(flag: boolean): string | boolean {
    if (flag) {
      return 'truthy'
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkBdQdwewE4GsDOsAWBTAdqAlgLYAOANpgTpHtgOagCGu1kmCAZvQMaYA0+boAJ5wArqBEpMoOADdWJOPQAmKALAAoZqw7dQnOAQJxsAJlABvDaFAsUkABRsS9GgC4bCEZgCU7uwmoaKxtMO0dnN1AOEklfUAAjODgyRmDbBycXd0TkzEY4-0DQAB8EpJTsDQBfDQ1OZxQ0AFEADyIzQlJySjR9Q2MzS3VrdPCsjy8CyADaAG400IyI92jY7PK87HnhkLDMyJyKqZm6UsPNi2DrPAExmm9LnetrBExIEQRcAHJpkUh0QRfK6gKqgTAxKRDZ7PV7vT5RegQ7bQmo7VGourGOygGSIgDMoAAvKBsJgYKBWu17N4AHSjVY+WagEBlXKpdT6bDY3EkAAsRJJZIpbRM1Lpi3sv0Z1hZhVoGiAA)

If you don't, the class method isn't a match for the interface definition. The interface is a contract your class must match, not a blueprint that affects how the class's declarations are interpreted.

Comment: Thanks for that. I skipped that implementation because  I was trying to achieve what was done in the first example where `method` implemented the `common` interface without declaring all the overloads. But I guess this can't be done with classes.
To complete the answer, here is the conditional type interface: [tsplay](https://tsplay.dev/m0ojON)

Comment: @mitsos1os - Ah, thanks, didn't realize you wanted both. :-)